# Assignment suppression flag in fscanf

Tags: c, scanf

Please have a look at this code snippet:

```
char line[80];
if(fscanf(stdin, "%*[\t\v\f ]%79[^\n]", line) != EOF)
        printf("%s\n", line);
```

Output:

```
$ gcc line.c -o line
$ ./line
 One space at the beginning.
One space at the beginning.
$ ./line
No space at the beginning.

$
```

Now In case of `No space at the beginning` why the whole string is not printed as it is ?

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3
```

Answer (score 2):

It fails because there is no match for `"%*[\t\v\f ]"`, so the subsequent format specifier `%79[^\n]` is not processed and `line` is not assigned. To skip leading white space replace the scanset with a leading space:

```
if(fscanf(stdin, " %79[^\n]", line) == 1)
    printf("%s\n", line);
```

Comment: `fscanf` fails in the case of `One space at the beginning` too though not at the very first character. And can't use whitespace here as it will consume the `\n` character which resides at the end of each line and this will create problem if there is an empty line. i.e. line containing `\n` only.

Comment: @rootkea, I am unsure what you mean by _not at the very first character_ ?

Comment: Sorry I meant `[\t\v\f ]` fails in the case of `One space at the beginning` too though not at the very first character.

Comment: @rootkea, is the objective to skip any leading whitespace on each line?

Comment: Parse individual lines from a file and then for each line print the contents of the line leaving leading whitespaces.

Comment: @rootkea, use `fgets()` to read a line. use `sscanf()` to extract from it.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` will fail on the first match `%*[\t\v\f ]` if there is no space, tabs or page break at the beginning of the line. Once it fails, it won't try to match the rest of the pattern.

Besides, you don't need to manually match for those characters, one space in the format string will expand to any number of white spaces in the input string. See the documentation of [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) to check which characters are considered whitespaces.

Comment: Sorry about that, accidentally edited your answer instead of my own.

Answer (score 0):

Your are having trouble as scanning quits if a field is not found as well explained by @hmjd.

Note: Using `fgets()` is a better approach, but sticking with OP style:

```
// consume select leading whitespaces, if any, but not \n
fscanf(stdin, "%*[\t\v\f ]");

// Scan non-eol chars
char line[80];
if (fscanf(stdin, "%79[^\n]", line) == 1) {
  printf("%s\n", line);
}

// scan a single EOL
char eol[2];
if (fscanf(stdin, "%1[\n]", eol) == 1) {
  ; // EOL found
}
```

By separating into 3 `fscanf()` calls, each format, in turn is attempted, even if an earlier one failed.